# win 32 console app crashes when running strcmp code

Tags: c

```
void emt_card_discount()
{
    char emt_card[8];
    char*none[5];
    int new_total_amt;

    printf("\tkey in EMT card number (7 figure) if present or type 'none': \n\t >> ");
    scanf_s("%s", &emt_card);

    if (strcmp(emt_card,"none") == 0)
    {
        printf("\tyour seat price is: %.2f\n",total_amt);
    }

    else
    { 
        new_total_amt = total_amt*0.15;
        printf("\tyour seat price is(RM):%.2f\n", new_total_amt);
    }
}
```

This is my code for strcmp.this particular basically functions to provide the user booking the ticket to enter card info to get a special discount..but whenever i get to this part of the code the whole console app crashes..

.

Comment: As long as the user don't input 8 (or more) characters there's nothing wrong with that `strcmp` call. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: By the way, `&emt_card` in the `scanf` call is semantically wrong. It works because it happens to point to the correct location, but it is the wrong type (the `"%s"` format expects a pointer to char, i.e. `char *`, but `&emt_card` is of type `char (*)[8]`). Use either `&emt_card[0]` or its equivalent `emt_card`.

Comment: Oh and I suggest you take some time to [read this `scanf_s` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx). Because *that's* the cause of the crash, not the `strcmp` call.

Comment: Reading documentation mostly is a good idea: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/w40768et.aspx

Answer (score 4):

`scanf_s()` is **not** a drop-in replacement for `scanf()`. With `scanf_s()`, a `%s`, `%c` or `%[` conversion needs **two** arguments, the second one is the size of the target buffer.

Originally, `scanf_s()` (and "friends") is a Microsoft idea, and the Microsoft definition is slightly different from the now standardized `scanf_s()`. The Microsoft version defines the size in *bytes* of type `unsigned`, while the C standard defines it in *elements* of type `rsize_t` (which is the same number here, but still incompatible ...).

Correct usage of `scanf_s()` would look like this in your code:

```
char emt_card[8];
[...]
int rc = scanf_s("%s", emt_card, 8U); // microsoft
int rc = scanf_s("%s", emt_card, (rsize_t)8); // standard C
if (rc < 1)
{
    // handle error, either EOF or 0 (buffer was too small for input)
}
```

Note also there's no *address-of* operator in the call. `emt_card` already evaluates to a pointer to the first element (`char *`), while `&emt_card` would be a pointer to the array (`char (*)[8]`). The values are the same, still `&emt_card` would have the wrong type, so it's undefined behavior.

---

The "funny" thing is that you forgot exactly the size which was the reason to introduce `scanf_s()` in the first place. `scanf("%s", ...)` is **alyways a bug** because it will overflow any buffer. But there's a way to write this code correctly with just `scanf()` as well by using a *field width*:

```
int rc = scanf("%7s", emt_card); // read up to 7 bytes, leaving room for the `0` byte
if (rc < 1)
{
    // handle error
}
```

The difference here is that if the input is too long, the `scanf()` with a field-width will just stop consuming input, while `scanf_s()` with a size given and without field-width would **fail** the conversion.

---

I'd personally suggest to never use `scanf_s()` and friends because of the incompatible definitions. `scanf()` is sufficient if you use field widths. On a side note, `scanf()` for interactive input is almost always very problematic, I'd suggest to not use it at all. See my [beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) for more information and alternatives.